# search in a document and just get the properties that match my search in elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, match, document

> in my index of elasticsearch, I have a type with multiple properties.
>   and each one have different values..
>
> now my question is:
>
> > in my search query i want to get just the result that are matched to mine.. not hole document! i want elastic get me just result that are matched! not all document with matched and not-matched result, that returned to me because of matched ones

thanks for your help friends..

---

here an example about my issue: 
for example in my document i have a property named folder, and it have some property, that can have multiple value..

```
"folder":  [
       [
      "employer_folder_id" => 142
      "status_id" => 140
      "folder" =>  [
        "id" => 142
        "employer_id" => 11
      ]
      "created_at" => "2017-04-12"
      "is_applied" => 1
      "hire_stage_id" => 144
    ]
     [
      "employer_folder_id" => 7922
      "status_id" => 141
      "folder" =>  [
        "id" => 7922
        "employer_id" => 11
      ]
      "created_at" => "2017-04-12"
      "is_applied" => 1
      "hire_stage_id" => 144
    ]
]
```

here i want to search for folders with status_id = 141,

but when i search it returns the hole document for me.. with other status ids... but i want to just return me status_id=141, and for other fields too

the folder its a property in my type..

Comment: Your question is confusing to me. Can you provide and example?

Comment: sure @MohammadMazraeh
for example in my document i have a property named folder, and it have some property, that can have multiple value.. 
''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good to provide your mapping and query.
I think that's because your array type is of `object` type. In this case elastic will flatten your `folder` property as a document  when each field is an array of values. Something like this:
**It is done at index time**

```
folder.status_id: [140, 144, 141, 144]
```

and that's why your query will return the hole documents.
You should try use `nested` object type.
[Useful Link](https://blogs.gnome.org/danni/2015/11/26/searching-for-documents-with-arrays-of-objects-using-elasticsearch/)

Comment: thanks @MohammadMazraeh im using laravel scout driver.. and cant find a way how to do mapping.. its my problem too..

Comment: I'm not familiar with laravel. can't you use `index template`s?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *fields* query to have only those field as result, which you need,For eg;

```
{
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [
                {
                    'term': {
                        'Key1': 'value1'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    'fields': [
        'Key1',
        'Key2',
        'Key3'
    ]
}
```

This will return all documents which have *key1* present whose value is *value1*. Each document will have only 3 fields, *'Key1','Key2',      'Key3'*.

Comment: thanks for your response friend.. but i have multiple field 'Key1','Key2','Key3' in my document..
and in my document it could be possible that, just one field 'Key1' have the match value and other 'Key1' fields dont match... and it could happen for the other 'Key2' and 'Key3' fields.. in this case how can i show just the right fields?